# How to resolve error: webpack.config.js, No Babel config file detected for ""

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I have a react native web app. And I try to run the app with the webpack.config.js file.

So I installed webpack and webpack-cli. And Added in package.json this:

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start, react-app-rewired start ",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js",
        "postinstall": "patch-package",
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
        "start-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --mode production --open"
    },

    "parserOptions": {
        "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
        "requireConfigFile": false
    },
```

and the webpack.config.js file looks:

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require("@expo/webpack-config");


module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);


    
    if (config.mode === "production") {
        config.devServer.compress = false;
    }

    return config;
};
```

This is the eslintrc file:

```
{
    "extends": "@react-native-community",

    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "printWidth": 120 }],
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "quotes": [2, "double", { "avoidEscape": true }]
    }
}
```

But I still get this error:

```
Parsing error: No Babel config file detected for C:\repos\Dierenwelzijn\DWL_frontend\webpack.config.js. Either disable config file checking with requireConfigFile: false, or configure Babel so that it can find the config files.eslint
```

But the file is located at this url.

Question: how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post your `.eslintrc.js` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue earlier. You need to add `requireConfigFile: false` to you `.eslintrc.js` file.

```
parserOptions: {
  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  requireConfigFile: false, // ADD THIS
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `.eslintrc.js`, add:

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": [
        {"mode": "auto"}
    ],
```

If not there, add too:

```
parserOptions: {
  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  requireConfigFile: false,
  ...
}
```